# python 3 not working

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, gedit

Specifically I get a type error that says the `pow()` function does not take strings or integers?

I am following code character for integer from this site
    http://hetland.org/writing/instant-hacking.html.

The Area Calculator function is what I am copying down. The only difference is that I am enclosing the strings after the print statements with parenthesis as per Python syntactical structure. I am using Python version 3.4.3 and Linux Mint Ubuntu 16.04.1. I am running on a an old HP EliteBook with an CORE i5 vPro processor x86_64.

I have  a number of images to help explain. 
The last image show that despite adding 1 as input the program prompts for the radius and that gives type error at the end. It does not matter what I put in input it skips the if statement and goes straight to prompting for radius. I realize there is a syntax error in the form of a the word calculator in the top comment. I fixed that.

Linux Version:

[image]

Python3 Version:

[image]

Area Calculator Code(mispelled word in comment)

[image]

Error in terminal:

[image]

Comment: See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Somone somehow did this for me with some javascript. Pretty slick. I followed suit and added more.

Comment: Please learn [ask]. In particular: **1:** Don't post images of code – see the link in my previous comment. **2:** Don't edit the word "SOLVED" into your question – [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer instead. **3:** Don't edit followup questions into your original question – ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `radius = int(input("Please enter the radius: "))` because currently you are asking for an input which by default is a string.  The `int()` function converts it to an integer.

See [documentation for more details](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#int) on this handy function.

Comment: I thank you greatly for your help. The int function helped with the runtime errors telling me that the pow() function didn't accept strings. Thank you for that.I will try to figure out how to post pics of the new situation, but basically there is still semantic errors. The semantic errors now are that the input I give to shape is 1 for rectangle ,but the prompt I get is for radius , the other is that regardless of what I enter for radius I just get the output "The area is" with nothing after wards.

Comment: @Rubberbandface My provider doesn't let me access that page and the code you gave does not mention `pow()`.  I'm more than happy to help further if you can provide me with some more details (script maybe), preferably in text for so I can run it for myself without coping manually.

Comment: Right , the pow() function is being called  in the second area variable in the else: statement. " area = 3.14*(radius**2)" I ma being hacked so my internets slow.Also mind hacked by DOD/CIA as described in "Project Soul Catcher" by Robert Duncan. Here is a the pow() documentation.   https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow   It says there that it is the equivalent of using **

Comment: @Rubberbandface Ok I did not notice this at the time but things when printing `print("The area is:"), area` should be *inside* the print statement.  IE `print("The area is:", area)`. That's a definite syntax error.

Comment: I don't know how to provide a script. I am a complete n00b. The site has code that should be the same as provided except I made it python3 friendly ,and added the int() function you helped me with. The main issue is with the area variables not showing up and the fact that it ignores the code ion the if statement.

Comment: @Rubberbandface  Posting code is easier than images.  Just paste it in and use 4 spaces or `` (the things next to the !) initially to format it and 4 spaces per indent after.  If it seems dodgy I guess it's Python 2

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question was provided by simon. Here is the code ``
    # Area calculation program

```
print ("Welcome to the area calculation program")
print ("---------------------------------------")
print

# print out the menu:
print ("Please select a shape:")
print ("1 Rectangle")
print ("2 Circle")

# Get the user's choice:
shape = int(input("> "))

# Calculate the area:
if shape == 1:
    height = int(input("Please enter the height: "))
    width = int(input("Please enter the width: "))
    area = height*width
    print ("The area is ", area)
else:
    radius = int(input("Please enter the radius: "))
    area = 3.14*(radius**2)
    print ("The area is ", area)
```

The answer was putting an int() function in front of the input functions so that the integer input would be recognized as such. The second issue was solved by placing the area variable to be printed out within the parenthesis. Thank you Simon!